# The factors "such as" population growth and the rise of the ocean level have to be considered - is it wierd to use "such as" this way?

Tags: word-usage, usage

It seems that people seldom use the phrase "such as" after a noun following a definite article; is my understanding correct?

**Example 1**

> Factors **such as** population growth and the rise of the ocean level have to be considered.

**Example 2**

> The factors **such as** population growth and the rise of the ocean level have to be considered.

If the noun follows a definite article, people seem to tend to use "including."

Is that correct?

**Example 3**

> The factors, **including** population growth and the rise of the ocean level, have to be considered.

Comment: Examples 2 and 3, should not have the word "The". Just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a set of factors has been mentioned before, it is odd to use *the factors* in examples 2 and 3.

Example 1 sounds natural.

It would not be odd to say *the factor of population growth*, referring to a single particular factor.